# How to load vms from a forgotten drive without having to import

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

This is an awkward problem. I keep my Hyper-V Virtual Machines in 2 different external hard drives that are different volumes on my host PC.

One of the drives could not be recognized for whatever reason and I was able to fix that although after the volume showed up again on my host PC, Hyper-V Manager no longer lists the Virtual Machines that are under that hard drive.

The only way I found to add them back is to import them as a new VM, but that is not practical.

I would like to hear from people who know better how I can have those VMs listed again in Hyper-V Manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Import-VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/import-vm?view=win10-ps) command with the `-Register` parameter to specify that the imported virtual machine is to be registered in-place.

```
Import-VM -Path "Path-to-VMCX" -Register
```